# How do I add a dropdown list of numbers 1 - 1000 as an extra profile field?

Tags: user-meta, profiles

I don't want to write out something like this from 1 to 1000:

```
        <select name="number_pick" id="number_pick" >    
        <option value="1" <?php selected( '1', get_the_author_meta( 'number', $user->ID ) ); ?>>1</option>
        <option value="2" <?php selected( '2', get_the_author_meta( 'number', $user->ID ) ); ?>>2</option>
        <option value="3" <?php selected( '3', get_the_author_meta( 'number', $user->ID ) ); ?>>3</option>
        </select>
```

So instead, I am trying to use a foreach statement to get from 1 to 1000.  I think I am close, but I have something wrong and I don't know what it is.

```
            <select name="number_pick" id="number_pick" >
            <?php foreach (range(0,1000) as $number)
            echo "<option value='$number' selected( '$number', get_the_author_meta( 'number_pick', $user->ID ) ) >$number</option>"; ?>
            </select>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing in the lines above?

Here is the complete code:

```
        <?php
            add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'show_extra_profile_fields' );
            add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'show_extra_profile_fields' );

            function show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
                <h3>Extra profile information</h3>
                <table class="form-table">
                    <tr>
                        <th><label for="number_pick">Pick A Number</label></th>
                        <td>
                            <select name="number_pick" id="number_pick" >
                                <?php foreach (range(0,1000) as $number)
         echo "<option value='$number' selected( '$number', get_the_author_meta( 'number_pick', $user->ID ) ) >$number</option>"; ?>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <?php }

            add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );
            add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );

            function save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
                if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
                    return false;
                update_usermeta( $user_id, 'number_pick', $_POST['gender'] );
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: This is a **PHP/HTML** question, not a **WordPress** question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can save the 1000 conditional checks by using `str_replace` and your code would be much more efficient, something like this:

```
//create the select options
$options ='';
for($i=1;$i<=1000;$i++) {
    $options.=  '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
}

//get the saved data
$saved = get_the_author_meta( 'number_pick', $user->ID );
$saved = (!empty($saved))? $saved: false;
if ($saved)
    //if there is a saved data set the option to selected
    $options = str_replace('value="'.$saved.'"','value="'.$saved.'" selected="selected"',$options);
//echo out the options
echo $options;
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked awesome.  Thanks, once again, Bainternet

Answer (score 1):

Fist off, why a dropdown of 1000 items? Why not using a textinput field and check if the input is between 1 and 1000?

But ok, the answer:

```
<?php for($number=1;$number<=1000;$number++) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $number; ?>" <?php selected( $number, get_the_author_meta( 'number_pick', $user->ID ); ?>><?php echo $number; ?></option>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

---

So your problem is with the saving.
`update_usermeta( $user_id, 'number_pick', $_POST['gender'] );` the $_POST name is gender here, shouldn't that be number_pick?

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'number_pick', $_POST['number_pick'] );
```

Btw: update_usermeta is deprecated, you should use update_user_meta() instead.